# How to inject mock objects in Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Following is the simulated situation, which I am facing while unit testing.

```
Sample Class

class FooService extends Service
{

    public static FooService sFooService;

    private Bar mBar = new Bar();
    //Other private objects

    @Override
    protected void onCreate()
    {
        sFooService = this;
    }

    public static FooService getInstance()
    {
        return sFooService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        sFooService = null;
    }

    public void doSomething()
    {
        //do Some stuff here
        if(done)
        {
            mBar.perfomAction(true);
            // Now this performAction method doing many stuffs using some other classes
            // that may have dependency and initialized from some else. Hence throwing exceptions.
            // Therefore need to mock Bar class. but how ??
        }
        else
        {
            mBar.perfomAction(false);
        }
    }
}

Sample Test Class


class FooTest extends ServiceTestCase<FooService>
{

    protected void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        super.setUp();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        startService(new Intent(getContext(), FooService.class));

    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception
    {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void testdoSomething()
    {
        Bar bar = mock(bar.class);
        doThrow(new RuntimeException re).when(bar).performAction(true);

        //How to inject bar mocked object?

        assertNotNull(FooService.getInstance());

        try
        {
            FooService.getInstance().doSomeThing();
            Assert.Fail("Runtime exception should be thrown");
        }
        catch (RuntimeException re)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Now, here how can I inject bar mocked object which is created using Mockito ?

I have googled this, and found that some guys suggested to create getter and setter for Bar class. Which I don't think is a valid solution, because there could be number of private object, that will be visible to outside FooService class.

Regards,
Yuvi

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor that takes in a `Bar`. If your tests are in the same Java package as your class (which is the common setup, especially if you use Maven), the constructor can be package scope.

```
class FooService extends Service {
  private static FooService sFooService;

  private final Bar mBar;

  // visible for testing constructor
  FooService(Bar bar) {
    mBar = bar;
  }

  // optional public constructor
  public FooService() {
    this(new Bar());
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think its good idea to create constructor for Android component classes. Also, what if I have Bar1 Bar2.. classes ?

Comment: @Yuvi all concrete classes have constructors so I don't understand your first concern. If your class has many dependencies, then it may violate the Single Responsibility Principle (in which case you many want to extract a class)